# Which nuget package holds the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll in Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I just got a new computer at work and started to migrate my projects to VS2013. Now the problem is that with Azure SDK 2.4 the DLL Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll is not included in it anymore.

I found this [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1b28274f-0dc7-4517-acf2-6cffc999d49f/azure-sdk-24-storageclient-vs2013-extensions?forum=windowsazuredevelopment) on the matter, were it was told that they were kept out of the 2.4 in order to keep it lighter and you need to add them in using NuGet.

OK, that's fair enough, but I've tried for hours to find the correct package with no luck. Anyone knows with package holds that DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll` which is really-really old version of Storage Client library (thus not recommended). But if you're trying to get this DLL, try this link: http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/1.7.0.